# Java: Accessing string within if statement

Tags: java, string, if-statement

Having a problem displaying a string that is declared within an If statement, here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

// This program reads a temp and prints its current state
public class P03_01_2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        // get temp
        System.out.print("Enter a temperature: ");
        if (in.hasNextDouble()) {
            double temp = in.nextDouble();

            // determine temp type and determine state

            System.out.print("Enter C for Celcius or F for Fahrenheit: ");
            String type = in.nextLine();
            if (type.equals("c") || type.equals("C")) {
                if (temp <= 0) {
                    String state = "frozen";
                } else if (temp >= 100) {
                    String state = "gaseous";
                } else {
                    String state = "water";
                }
            }
            if (type.equals("f") || type.equals("F")) {
                if (temp <= 32) {
                    String state = "frozen";
                } else if (temp >= 212) {
                    String state = "gaseous";
                } else {
                    String state = "water";
                }
            } else if ((!type.equals("c") || !type.equals("C") || !type.equals("f") || !type.equals("F"))) {
                System.out.print("Not valid input.");
                System.exit(0);

            } else {
                System.out.println("Not valid input.");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            System.out.println("The state of the water is " + state);

        }
    }
}
```

I have tried putting "String state = null before" the first if statement, but keep getting errors.......Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    // get temp
    System.out.print("Enter a temperature: ");
    if (in.hasNextDouble()) {
        double temp = in.nextDouble();

        // determine temp type and determine state

        System.out.print("Enter C for Celcius or F for Fahrenheit: ");
        String type = in.nextLine();
        if (type.equals("c") || type.equals("C")) {
            if (temp <= 0) {
                String state = "frozen";
            } else if (temp >= 100) {
                String state = "gaseous";
            } else {
                String state = "water";
            }
        }
        String state = null;
        if (type.equals("f") || type.equals("F")) {
            if (temp <= 32) {
                state = "frozen";
            } else if (temp >= 212) {
                state = "gaseous";
            } else {
                state = "water";
            }
        } else if ((!type.equals("c") || !type.equals("C") || !type.equals("f") || !type.equals("F"))) {
            System.out.print("Not valid input.");
            System.exit(0);

        } else {
            System.out.println("Not valid input.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        System.out.println("The state of the water is " + state);

    }
}
```

`state` has to be in scope... Be aware that it might now be `null`. This will not cause an error though...

Answer (score 7):

You're declaring the variable within each block. i.e. each declaration is in its own block and scoped separately.

```
String state = null;
if (...) {
   String state = "";
   // this is a different variable to 'state' outside the block!
}
```

You need to *declare* the variable outside the blocks, and then *initialise* within e.g.

```
String state = null;
if (...) {
   state = "";
}

// state is still visible here
```

Here's a [simple tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/VariableScope.htm) on the concept of scope within Java.

Comment: thank you, i have been learning java for the last week and this has been killing for for a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to put 'String state = null' then you should only assign the value for 'state' inside if like state='frozen' not String state = frozen.